# DQL query ManyToMany IN

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

This query in not working. What could be wrong? Post has author(User entity). User has Following(ManyToMany self-directing)

I'm trying to get all Posts of the Users which I'm following

```
$userId = $this->getUser()->getId();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $qb;
$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u.following')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->where('u.id = :userId');

    $qb->select('p')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Post', 'p')
    ->where($qb->expr()->In('p.author', $qb2->getDQL()));

    $qb->setParameter('userId', $userId);
    $dql = $qb->getDQL();
```

Comment: You don't need 2 query builders and you don't need to use DQL inside where.

You probably want to use innerJoin :), but update your question with information about what you're trying to get... Posts for current user?

Comment: @revengeance Can you please show some example of it in this context. I'm no sure that I know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your code is in repository as it should be...

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Controller/PostController.php**</kbd>

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$myResultCollection=$em->getRepository(Post::class)->myCustomQuery($this->getUser());
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Repository/PostRepository.php**</kbd>

```
public function myCustomQuery(User $user) {
    $em=$this->getEntityManager();
    $qb=$em->createQueryBuilder();

    return $qb->select("p")
              ->from(Post::class, "p")
              ->where($qb->expr()->in("p.author",
                  $qb->select("u.following")
                     ->from(User::class, "u")
                     ->where("u.id=:USERID")
                     ->getDQL()))
              ->setParameters(array('USERID'=>$user->getId()))
              ->getQuery()
              ->execute();
}
```

As side note, you should be careful with quotes.
Make sure to use double quotes when using DQL (it's true for SQL too).
The reason is because you need simple quote for strings in queries.

Comment: @ВячеславРешетняков What is the returned error with this?

Comment: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 105: Error: Expected end of string, got 'u'

Comment: Most of the time, it's because one parameter used is null, in this case, `User`. Add this before the `return`  statement: `dump($user); exit();`. Does the dump show a correct user entity?

Comment: That is not the case... User is defined in this case

Comment: Xmmm... Hard to guess what is wrong... What if you remove `getDQL()` in the sub query @ВячеславРешетняков?

Comment: I need to get the DQL... I'm using it in the knp_pagination